# How to validate UUID v4 in Go?

Tags: go

I have the following piece of code:

```
func GetUUIDValidator(text string) bool {
    r, _ := regexp.Compile("/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[89aAbB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}/")
    return r.Match([]byte(text))
}
```

But when I pass `fbd3036f-0f1c-4e98-b71c-d4cd61213f90` as a value, I got `false`, while indeed it is an UUID v4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, there is `regex.MustCompile` for usage like the one in your code. Also, Go style regexes don't use // delimiters. Read the documentation to understand how Go regex work.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try with...

```
func IsValidUUID(uuid string) bool {
    r := regexp.MustCompile("^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-4[a-fA-F0-9]{3}-[8|9|aA|bB][a-fA-F0-9]{3}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$")
    return r.MatchString(uuid)
}
```

Live example: https://play.golang.org/p/a4Z-Jn4EvG

**Note:** as others have said, validating UUIDs with regular expressions can be slow. Consider other options too if you need better performance.

Comment: You're checking [1-5] in the third section, which allows this to match for non uuid 4 strings. The title of this question asks for uuid v4. Change [1-5] to 4 and it works as requested.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. Just updated it, plus updated the 4th section too.

Comment: Unfortunately this regex is incorrect in that it matches a larger set of strings than valid UUID. for example if the starting chunk is larger than 8 characters it will still match. you will want 
regexp.MustCompile("^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[8|9|a|b][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}$")

Comment: @ForeverStudent you're right! I'm updating the answer. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: One more thing: sometimes you use `[a-f]` and sometimes `[aAbB]`, thereby allowing uppercase letters only in a few places.

Comment: @RolandIllig technically hex is part of the uuid standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122 
if you look at my comment I only used lowercase but most important is to be consistent

Comment: @RolandIllig nice! Just modified the code and the example. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. I have used UUID generated from MySQL DB and it's giving false for this UUID.

Comment: @PranaySaha you should share the ID you got from MySQL in order for us to provide you with a more up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 102):

Regex is expensive. The following approach is [~18x times faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051675/how-to-validate-uuid-v4-in-go/46315070?noredirect=1#comment85002123_46315070) than the regex version.

Use something like https://godoc.org/github.com/google/uuid#Parse instead.

```
import "github.com/google/uuid"

func IsValidUUID(u string) bool {
    _, err := uuid.Parse(u)
    return err == nil
 }
```

Comment: Good but also introduce a dependency to another library.

Comment: Any examples on why RegExp would be expensive? You do know that in Go RegExps are constant in time depending on the input, right?

Comment: I believe Go's implementation is linear O(n) not constant O(1). Since UUIDs are fixed size, I don't think it matters too much anyway. I ran a quick benchmark, it's 628 ns/op for the regexp version and 34.8 ns/op for the "uuid.Parse" approach. https://gist.github.com/mattes/69a4ab7027b9e8ee952b5843e7ca6955

Answer (score 9):

You can utilize satori/go.uuid package to accomplish this:

```
import "github.com/satori/go.uuid"

func IsValidUUID(u string) bool {
  _, err := uuid.FromString(u)
  return err == nil
}
```

This package is widely used for UUID operations: https://github.com/satori/go.uuid

Comment: I updated https://gist.github.com/mattes/69a4ab7027b9e8ee952b5843e7ca6955 to benchmark satori/go.uuid vs google/uuid. Google's UUID check is 3.3x faster than this one.

Answer (score 5):

In case you would be validating it as attribute of a struct, there is an awesome golang library straight from the Go called validator https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9 which you can use to validate all kinds of fields nested structures by provided built-in validators as well as complete custom validation methods. All you need to do is just add proper tags to the fields

```
import "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"

type myObject struct {
    UID string `validate:"required,uuid4"`
}

func validate(obj *myObject) {
    validate := validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(obj)
}
```

It provides structured field errors and other relevant data from it.

Comment: `validator.v10` is out (v9 is on maintenance only since 2019, meaning it won't receive any further features, just bug & security fixes), although the docs still refer to `v9`!